# Integration limits and probability density

Tags: statistics

So I've got the density function for the $2$-dimensional random variable $(X,Y)$: $$p(x,y) = \frac{4}{3}xe^{-x-y} $$ when $ 0 < y < x$. Otherwise, it's $0$.

I am now interested in the density of the random variable $W = X + Y$. This is given by:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x,w-x)dx$$

Fine enough, but now I run into a problem I always have... what are all the limits concerning this problem? Not just for the integral, but for $W$ as a random variable as well; i.e. when does its density function equal $0$, and when does it equal a function $d(w)$?

Answer (score 2):

As usual, the solution is to write the PDFs correctly, that is, as *functions defined on their full domain, including indicator functions*. Here, the density $p$ is defined *on the whole plane $\mathbb R^2$* by $$p(x,y)=\tfrac43x\mathrm e^{-x-y}\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt x},$$ hence the density $q$ of $X+Y$ is defined *on the whole line $\mathbb R$* by $$q(w)=\int_\mathbb R p(x,w-x)\mathrm dx=\int_\mathbb R \tfrac43x\mathrm e^{-w}\mathbf 1_{0\lt w-x\lt x}\mathrm dx=\tfrac43\mathrm e^{-w}\mathbf 1_{w\gt0}\int_\mathbb R x\mathbf 1_{w/2\lt x\lt w}\mathrm dx,$$ that is, $$q(w)=\tfrac43\mathrm e^{-w}\mathbf 1_{w\gt0}\int_{w/2}^w x\mathrm dx=\tfrac23\mathrm e^{-w}\mathbf 1_{w\gt0}\left.\ x^2\right|_{w/2}^w=\tfrac12w^2\mathrm e^{-w}\mathbf 1_{w\gt0}.$$

Comment: This is what I don't understand; $$\int_\mathbb R \tfrac43x\mathrm e^{-w}\mathbf 1_{0\lt w-x\lt x}\mathrm dx=\tfrac43\mathrm e^{-w}\mathbf 1_{w\gt0}\int_\mathbb R x\mathbf 1_{w/2\lt x\lt w}\mathrm dx,$$ How are those two equal? I understand how we reach the expression on the left, but not the one on the right

Comment: $$\mathbf 1_{0\lt w-x\lt x}=\mathbf 1_{x\lt w\lt2x}=\mathbf 1_{w\gt0}\mathbf 1_{w/2\lt x\lt w}$$

Comment: @Did  how did you come up with limits $w$ and $w\over 2$ ?

Comment: @Andy See my previous comment.