# $\Pr(X+Y\geq1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two random variables X and Y have the following joint pdf:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)\begin{cases}10x^{2}y & 0<x<1,0<y<x\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I am asked to find the marginal pdf of $X$, followed by the conditional pdf of $Y$ given $X=x$, and finally to evaluate $\Pr(X+Y\geq1)$.

So far, I've managed the following (and am hoping it is correct):

For the marginal pdf of $X$,
\begin{align*}
f_{X}(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\;dy\\
&=\int_{0}^{x}10x^{2}y\;dy\text{ [do I integrate from 0 to $x$ here?]}\\
&=10x^{2}\frac{y^{2}}{2}\bigg|^{y=x}_{y=0}\\
&=5x^{4}
\end{align*}

Assuming that the above is correct, for the conditional pdf of $Y$ given $X$, I have:
\begin{align*}
f_{Y|X}(y|x)&=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X}(x,y)}\\
&=\frac{10x^{2}y}{5x^{4}}\\
&=\frac{2y}{x^{2}}
\end{align*}

I'm not sure whether the above is correct, and any help would be appreciated if I have any errors in my understanding. But I am not sure at all how to proceed with $\Pr(X+Y\geq1)$. I've noticed [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089887/integration-limits-and-probability-density) seems relevant but the contents within are pretty much new to me and the mathematics involved is a little bit too advanced for my level (I'm only first-year under-grad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in deriving the marginal pdf of $X$ and the conditional pdf of $Y$ given $X=x$. Now, for the last part, you want to integrate the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ over all points $(x,y)$ such that $x+y\geq 1$.
We have
\begin{align*}
P(X+Y \geq 1) &= P(Y \geq 1-X) \\
&= \int\limits_{\frac12}^{1} \int\limits_{1-x}^{x} 10x^2 y \;\mathrm{d}y \;\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

The limits of integration for $y$ should make sense. I urge you to draw a picture of the support, and the region you wish to integrate to make it clearer to yourself. You will then see that $x$ must be greater than $\frac12$, but of course less than $1$, given the support of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm confident I can take it from here. Much appreciated!